# Previous polyline line is not removing because of animation?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-animation, google-polyline

I have created the `polyline` from **source to destination** but if user has chosen the another road so in that case a new `polyline` is created but the issue is previous `polyline` is not getting removed because of `animations`.

Please look at the image for issue:[image]

And my animations is working like this, first black color line will move to source to destination with animation and then grey color line.

[image].

I am creating the `polyline` with animation & in **onLocationChanged()** `polyline` is being created. Every time when **onLocationChanged()** called, a new `polyline` is created.

This is my **onLocationChanged()** method:

```
@Override
    public void onLocationChanged(final Location location) {
        super.onLocationChanged(location);
        mLat = location.getLatitude();
        mLng = location.getLongitude();

        LatLng myLatLngCurrentONlocationChnage = new LatLng(mLat, mLng);

        if (btnYesBooking || isBookingReserve) {
            mSearchComplete.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            String url = getDirectionsUrl(myLatLngCurrentONlocationChnage, myLatLngFinalDestinationClicked);

            DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();

            // Start downloading json data from Google Directions API
            downloadTask.execute(url);

            myDestinationBookingMarker = mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(myLatLngFinalDestinationClicked)
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.red_pin)));
            addMarker(mGoogleMapCar, mLat, mLng);
}
```

Please have a look into the onPostExecute() method where animation code is implemented.

```
@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> result) {

            PolylineOptions lineOptions = null;
            if (result != null) {
                // Traversing through all the routes
                for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
                    points = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
                    lineOptions = new PolylineOptions();

                    // Fetching i-th route
                    final List<HashMap<String, String>> path = result.get(i);

                    // Fetching all the points in i-th route
                    for (int j = 0; j < path.size(); j++) {
                        HashMap<String, String> point = path.get(j);
                        if (j == 0) {    // Get distance from the list
                            estimateDistance = (String) point.get("distance");

                            continue;
                        } else if (j == 1) { // Get duration from the list
                            estimeteDuration = (String) point.get("duration");
                            continue;
                        }

                        double lat = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lat"));
                        double lng = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lng"));
                        LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lng);
                        // points.clear();
                        points.add(position);
                    }


                    if (estimeteDuration != null) {
                        mTvEstimatedTime.setText("Estimated Time to reach: " + estimeteDuration);
                        mSearchComplete.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        mTxtEstimateArrivalTime.setText(estimeteDuration);


                    }
                    mTvEstimatedTime.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    mTxtEstimateArrivalTime.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    mRecyclerViewHotspot.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    mDetailLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    mParkingdetailLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    lineOptions.addAll(points);
                }

                LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
                for (LatLng latLng : points) {
                    builder.include(latLng);
                }
                polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
                polylineOptions.color(Color.GRAY);
                polylineOptions.width(12);
                polylineOptions.startCap(new SquareCap());
                polylineOptions.endCap(new SquareCap());
                polylineOptions.jointType(ROUND);
                polylineOptions.addAll(points);
                greyPolyLine = mGoogleMap.addPolyline(polylineOptions);

                blackPolylineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
                blackPolylineOptions.width(12);
                blackPolylineOptions.color(Color.BLACK);
                blackPolylineOptions.startCap(new SquareCap());
                blackPolylineOptions.endCap(new SquareCap());
                blackPolylineOptions.jointType(ROUND);

                blackPolyline = mGoogleMap.addPolyline(blackPolylineOptions);
                polylineAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(0, 100);
                polylineAnimator.setDuration(700);
                polylineAnimator.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
                polylineAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {

                        List<LatLng> points = greyPolyLine.getPoints();
                        int percentValue = (int) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
                        int size = points.size();
                        int newPoints = (int) (size * (percentValue / 100.0f));
                        List<LatLng> p = points.subList(0, newPoints);
                        blackPolyline.setPoints(p);


                    }
                });


                polylineAnimator.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                        List<LatLng> greyLatLng = greyPolyLine.getPoints();
                        if (greyLatLng != null) {
                            greyLatLng.clear();

                        }
                        polylineAnimator.start();

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
                        polylineAnimator.cancel();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

                    }
                });

                polylineAnimator.start();


            }
            mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(false);
            zoomRoute(mGoogleMap, points);

        }
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Where you are clearing your Polyline

Comment: I have tried that too in onPostExecute(). if(greyPolyline!null) greyPolyline.remove(); but it did not work.

Comment: Do you have any solution about clearing the polyline ? Please help what to change.

Comment: Check if your control is coming inside if condition. If yes, then add map.Cear().

Comment: I cannot call map.clear(); becuase in other locations in map i have so many markers so if i call clear method it will remove everything.

Comment: just check if map.clear is working there or not. Because the code which you are using to remove Polyline is correct. First check if control enters the for loop or not.

Comment: Hi, I am facing same issue, have you found any solution ?